# Модульность в JavaScript - доступность переменной

Tags: javascript, объекты, модули

Создал некий модуль:

```
var module= (function () {
    //мой объект.
    var object = [];
    return {
       //функции...
    }
})();
```

Почему я не могу обратиться к этому объекту в другом файле? Обращаюсь так:  `module.object` но пишет что не известная переменная. 
Как быть? может что-то подскажете.

Comment: У вас неправильный комментарий в конце.

Comment: Там должно быть не "функции", а "публичные свойства".

Comment: Ваш `object` не является публичным свойством - а потому не виден снаружи.

Comment: [Mastering the Module Pattern](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/)

Answer (score 3):

Ключевое слово `var` в *JavaScript* объявляет ***локальную*** переменную, которая видна только внутри функции. Чтобы объявить свойство, которое видно снаружи, нужно делать так:

```
var module = (function() {
    return {
        object: []
    };
})();
```

Но я бы рекомендовал сделать модуль чуть иначе:

```
var module = new function() {
    this.object = [];
}
```

Comment: ой не, в первом примере не через _this_ надо иначе в глобальный объект добавится

Comment: @Grundy Нормально всё. В обычном режиме добавляется к функции, в строгом `this===undefined`.Второй вариант корректно работает в обоих режимах.

Comment: неа, в нормальном режиме как раз глобальному объекту, потому что **без _new_** вызывается, соответственно в сторогом исключение

Comment: @Grundy https://jsfiddle.net/pcdqy1m3/2/ В трёх браузерах проверил.

Comment: @kff в первом фрагменте: `this.object = [];` - здесь `this` - это `window`, соответственно, `module` - тоже `window`

Comment: @Igor Тьфу, блин! Действительно... Что-то туплю... Вероятно, из-за позднего времени...

Comment: @kff, ну и вот пример, чтобы наверняка :-) https://jsfiddle.net/pcdqy1m3/3/

Comment: @Grundy Пошёл пить йад и убивать себя ап стену... :'(